# Stuck in a loop after switch in c

Tags: c

```
while (1)
{
    c = getchar();

    switch(state)
    {
      case 0:
          if((GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_0) == Bit_SET))
          {
              state=1;
          }

          if ( c=='p')
          {
              state = 2;
          }
          break;

      case 1 :
          if((GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_0) != Bit_SET))
          {
              state = 0;
          }
          break;

      case 2:
          iprintf("%s",led_name_arr[i]);
          if (c=='r')
          {
              state=0;
          }
          break;

    }
}
```

I want to print the printf and then reach state2 .. how can this be achieved .below is what i have tried and where i am stuck .

psuedocode:

```
if ( c==P)
{
  printf(" hi");
  state 2;
}
```

** in this case the printf statement does not get executed **
or

```
case 2:
  iprintf("%s",led_name_arr[i]);
  if (c=='r')
  {
    state=0;
  }
  break;
```

** in this case the printf statement keeps printing in a loop **

i dont want the while loop to stop , in a continuous loop i want case 0 keeps working , but when it get the input p .. it pauses and executes the printf ... and waits till it gets a r to resume case 0 .... Thus the program never halts but waits to either get "P" or "R" to execute each case... I hope i make sense

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: how about indenting your code?

Comment: Dont put extra {} braces inside you cases. They will confuse you.

Comment: @CarlNorum It does have a break .. check there are 3 breaks in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure what you are asking but i m pretty sure what you want in case 2 is something like this:

```
case 2:
  iprintf("%s",led_name_arr[i]);
  while(c!='r')
  {
      c = getchar();
  }
  state=0;
  break;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `break`s are breaking out of the `switch ... case` not the `while`. You'll need to use some kind of boolean flag to break out of the outer loop, e.g.:

```
bool someflag = true;
while(someflag){

   switch(something){
      case a:
         someflag = false; // set the flag so we break out of the loop
         break;            // break out of the switch-case so we don't enter case b
      case b:
         // do something else
         break;
   }
}
```

`-------- EDIT, because I misunderstood the question ------------`

I think you need an extra state in your logic, right now (ignoring state 1), you have two states:

1. Wait for  a `p`, when you get one, goto 2.
2. `printf` for each character until you get an `r`, then goto 1

What you want is:

1. Wait for a `p`, when you get one, goto 2.
2. Do a `printf`, then goto 3.
3. Wait for an `r`, when you get one, goto 1.

Comment: but i dont want the while loop to stop , at no moment do i want the while loop to stop... this will break the while loop... its like this case 0 keeps working , but when it get p .. it pauses and executes the printf ... and waits till it gets a r to resume case 0 .... I hope you get what i mean

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Well, you're going to state 2 when you get a `p`, and then you're waiting for an `r` before you go back to state 0. So basically you will have one `printf` for each character you enter after the `p`, until you enter an `r`. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: I think I understand your question now, I edited my answer to add more info.

Comment: yes you have got that correct , i am still at the point where it keeps printing

Answer (score 1):

You've created an infinite loop with the while (1) statement that has no possible exit.  The break statements within the switch apply to the switch statement, *not* the while loop.  You need another break statement outside the switch.

Answer (score 0):

well,
initialize state to 0

compile and run the program

first time enter p // here state =2

then enter r // here state = 0

....continue in a loop due to while(1)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not breaking the while(1) loop. Use one more break for while loop.